# git Plugins for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I know EGit is the most popular git plugin available for Eclipse. It comes with the original package.

But, I would like to explore a bit before we decide on which plugin to use in our project. Can you guys suggest me some other plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Java side, there isn't many more implementation.

Remember that you don't have to use Egit directly: you can access git features through the plugin on top of which EGit is built:

**[JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)**.

The **[unit tests for JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api)** provides for a good set of examples.

Comment: Thanks.. but is not EGit a plugin? or is it a project?

Comment: Egit is a plugin built on top of another plugin JGit: Egit provides the GUI, JGit provides the git features.